# How to make Vim quickfix list launch files in a new tab?

Tags: vim, tabs

Say, I have the following mapping:

```
map <F4> :execute "vimgrep /" .expand("<cword>") . "/j **" <Bar> cw<CR>
```

which (recursively) greps the current directory for instances of the word under the cursor and opens these files in the quickfix list window.

From the quickfix window, how do I launch the file that I open into a new tab? <kbd>Enter</kbd> just changes my current buffer in the window to that new file.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

Quickfix-window commands respect the `switchbuf` option when creating
the buffer. The `switchbuf` option has the `newtab` specifier that
instructs Vim to open a new tab page before loading the buffer to
switch to. If one adds this key to the option via

```
:set switchbuf+=newtab
```

the entries in the quickfix window will be opened in separate tab
pages.

There is the `usetab` specifier that also might be useful in this
case. It prescribes Vim to switch to an existing tab page if it
contains a window displaying the target buffer, instead of duplicating
it in a new tab. If it is desirable, one can throw that in, too:

```
:set switchbuf+=usetab,newtab
```

The value of `switchbuf` also (partially) affects other
buffer-switching commands, such as `:bfirst`, `:blast`, `:sbuffer`,
`:sbnext`, and `:sbprevious`.

Comment: wow. best answer ever. This is exactly what I was hoping to achieve! The `usetab` option is incredibly convenient as well! Thank you * ∞

Answer (score 7):

How about trying [QFEnter](https://github.com/yssl/QFEnter) plugin?
You can open each item in a new tab or a new vertical/horizontal split window without changing `switchbuf` option.
It also allows you to open multiple quickfix items at once with a visual selection block.

Comment: I like your plugin. It would be even better if you had all of the mappings the Ack plugin has, possibly the same: https://github.com/mileszs/ack.vim#keyboard-shortcuts. I also wanted to open a new tab without a quickfix window.

Comment: Thanks. You can set g:qfenter_enable_autoquickfix to 0 not to open quickfix in a new tab.

Answer (score 7):

```
autocmd FileType qf nnoremap <buffer> <Enter> <C-W><Enter><C-W>T
```

also works if you use:

```
tab copen
```

which would otherwise first split the window, even with `set switchbuf+=newtab`.

See also: https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/6996/how-to-make-enter-open-new-tabs-for-the-quickfix-window-when-it-is-opened-with