# How to open easygrep searched results in new tab on VIM?

Tags: vim, vimgrep

I have recently started using [easygrep](https://github.com/vim-scripts/EasyGrep), I haven't figured out how open the results in new tab on hitting enter. I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11504743/vim-easygrep-opens-split-windows-and-loads-each-searched-file#answer-14806368) solution but didn't work, I believe that solution was to open in split tab but I want it to open in new tab.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

look at this link [Vim quickfix list launch files in new tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6852763/vim-quickfix-list-launch-files-in-new-tab)

how to open easygrep search result is about your quickfix config.
u can try this [plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4778). 
or just add `set switchbuf+=usetab,newtab` to your .vimrc file